# connect with ssh to Amazon Elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to run a python script, (which I have run on a docker ubuntu installation) on AWS. It sends data to from Twitter to Elastic Search. I want to run it on Amazon Elasticsearch Service. I have set up Amazon Elasticsearch Service on AWS but I don't know how to get the script into the system and get it running.

1. What would the ssh be to access the Elastic Search Server?
2. Once I am able to access it where would I place a python script in order to feed data into the Elasticsearch server?

I tried

PS C:\Users\hpBill> ssh root@search-wbcelastic-*******.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/
but just get this:

ssh.exe": search-wbcelastic-**********.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/: no address associated with name

I have this information

**Domain status**
Active

**Endpoint**
search-wbcelastic-*********.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com

**Domain ARN**
arn:aws:es:us-e******1:domain/wbcelastic

**Kibana**
search-wbcelastic-********.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot SSH directly into AWS Cloud Search. So that SSH command will never work. You have two option to run the Python script either launch a EC2 instance with AWS CLI or store and run the script from your local machine with AWS CLI. Here is the developer guide for the AWS CLI for Cloud Search

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/using-cloudsearch-command-line-tools.html